# Someone else's legit question deleted

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, deleted-questions

*(Edited to be a generic question; see old version if you're curious about specifics)*

I googled a question (Q) I had and the only hit was to a deleted (but cached) Q here and it (the Google-cached copy) looks like a legit Q to me.

Should the Q I found be undeleted?  If not I can just post a new Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The question](https://superuser.com/questions/1466385/i-have-two-files-with-the-same-name-in-the-same-folder-in-google-drive-how-do-i) was deleted by the [roomba](https://superuser.com/help/roomba) a month ago.

That doesn't mean it was "bad", it was simply ignored and had neither votes nor answers.

> If the question is more than 365 days old, and ...
>
> - has a score of 0 or less, or a score of 1 and a deleted owner
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has view count <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments
> - isn't on a meta site
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are termed "abandoned"
> questions (`RemoveAbandonedQuestions`).

Rather than undeleting a question that OP has likely given up on it would be better for you to post a new question, though the *online sharing* features of Google Drive may well be off topic here and better off at [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hmmm.... What is roomba?

Comment: @WasifHasan https://www.irobot.co.uk/en-GB/roomba by extension our "roomba" is a bot that goes around automatically cleaning things up.